# OpenCV check powder level

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

what is the best way to check the level of the powder in the case with OpenCV?

[image: powder]

I tried HSV filtering to get the gery color of the powder.
But only with bad results.
Also tried with edge and blob detection, but still no good results.

Comment: If the powder is always in this configuration you can 
- detect the inside of the golden thing using round contour detection and color filtering
- on top of that apply edge filtering and remove the golden part to keep only the powder

Comment: don't do it optically. just stick a probe in there (*a dull stick*), until it hits the "powder", then determine the location of the probe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm no, I scanned vertically in the middle of the image and determined the average color of a 20 pixel line.

Then I checked whether the average color of the line is gray.

That works perfectly.

[image]

https://github.com/ripper121/python-powder-level